# Can't save Main Object with giving only ID of Nested Object - giving TransientObjectException Many to many relationship is used

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, cascade

Let me first introduce my whole problem,
I have a UserEntity like this

```
@Entity
public class UserEntity extends IdDescriptionStateMetaEntity {

  //.. other members  

  @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "role_user",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private List<RoleEntity> roles;

  // getter and setter
}
```

and also have RoleEntity

`@Entity public class RoleEntity extends IdDescriptionStateMetaEntity { //fields related to role }`

now, I always have role with ID 1 in database.

I just want to save UserEntity with giving id of role. as role always be there in database.

```
@Transactional
    public UserEntity createUser(){

        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
        
        List<RoleEntity> roleEntities = new ArrayList<>();
        
        RoleEntity roleEntity = new RoleEntity();
        roleEntity.setId("1");
        roleEntities.add(roleEntity);
        userEntity.setRoles(roleEntities);

        userEntity = userRepository.save(userEntity);
        return userEntity;
    }
```

When the above method calls it gives exception

`TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.model.RoleEntity`

I Tried giving Cascade.Merge in manytomany annotation, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

you can first find roles from DB and set that to userEntity and then save that in DB

Comment: Thanks, that works but I wanted to know the solution without doing that. Is there any ?

Comment: I think by define your roles in userEntity with keyword transient your issue will be done